# Wraping BOOST_LOG_SEV macro to another macro

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, metaprogramming

Trying to wrap BOOST_LOG_SEV macro to LOG_SS_BOOST :

```
#define LOG_SS_BOOST (value) do { BOOST_LOG_SEV (lg,boost::log::trivial::debug)<<value; } while (0)
```

But have errors during compilation:

```
Error   58  error C2065: 'value' : undeclared identifier    
Error   59  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'do' 
Error   60  error C2065: 'value' : undeclared identifier    
Error   61  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '('
```

What is wrong and how to wrap it in correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just should remove space before macro param, i.e:

```
#define LOG_SS_BOOST(value) do { BOOST_LOG_SEV (lg,boost::log::trivial::debug)<<value; } while (0)
```